# layout problem: keeping a fixed width in CSS with varying text

Tags: css, text, layout, width

The "span" tag that encompasses the text I'm trying to display is of 500px width.

Now, every time I insert a text longer than that width, it crosses over to complete the text. That only happens when the text has no spaces (like:

```
sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
```

you get the picture.

I've tried setting max-width, but it doesn't help either.

Any suggestions? (I'd hate to have to cut the text with php)

Comment: So what do you want to happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`word-wrap: break-word`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/WD-css3-text-20070306/#word-wrap)

It's supported in IE, Firefox 3.5, Chrome, Safari and Opera 10.50. It's even supported in old versions of IE, since it's a Microsoft invention which is now part of CSS3.

You can [see a preview here](http://www.css3.info/preview/word-wrap/).

Comment: merci beaucoup, that's what i've been looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Do you also hate to cut the text with CSS? Try to use `overflow: hidden`. But that will cut the text.

I don't know about the structure of your text, but if you're really expecting words long as in your example, how about inserting a space into looooong words that would otherwise break your layout and let HTML word-wrap take care of the line breaks?